# Change "return key" on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

Anyone have any idea how to replace the "Return" key on the iPhone keyboard with a hashtag key and @ symbol key? Instagram utilizes this on their comment system, so it should be possible, but I can't seem to find anything in the Apple documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set the keyboard type to `UIKeyboardTypeTwitter`

Comment: @mr.VVoo doc says _Available in iOS 5.0 and later._

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko: Sorry, i also meant 5 :)